# What is a Narcissistic Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word has a certain property, I call it a Narcissistic Word™. If it definitively does not have that property, I call it an Echoing Word™.

You can use the examples below to find the property:

| Narcissistic™ | Echoing™ |
| --- | --- |
| RUDDY | HEALTHY |
| CHAOTIC | DEVILISH |
| COMPOSED | DECOMPOSED |
| COMPOSITE | VERSATILE |
| MOSTLY | SURPASSING |
| VETERAN | BANDIT |
| UPTIGHT | SHY |
| NARCISSISTIC | VAIN |
| ISOLATED | RETILEABLE |
| EXPLAIN | SCIENTIFIC |
| REFRESHING | ROTTEN |
| DISTASTEFUL | VENOMOUS |
| UNCOPYRIGHTABLE | ANNAGRAMMABLE |
| VIRIDESCENT | FANTASTICAL |

And a CSV version:

```
RUDDY, HEALTHY
CHAOTIC, DEVILISH
COMPOSED, DECOMPOSED
COMPOSITE, VERSATILE
MOSTLY, SURPASSING
VETERAN, BANDIT
UPTIGHT, SHY
NARCISSISTIC, VAIN
ISOLATED, RETILEABLE
EXPLAIN, SCIENTIFIC
REFRESHING, ROTTEN
DISTASTEFUL, VENOMOUS
UNCOPYRIGHTABLE, ANNAGRAMMABLE
VIRIDESCENT, FANTASTICAL
```

Comment: Did you make a mistake with UPTIGHT?

Comment: Oops, yes I did, looks like my notes parsed G as 3, rather than 2. Thanks.

Comment: ANNAGRAMMABLE or ANAGRAMMABLE?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All the words which appear in the table in the question

> have appeared in the title of one of these Word™ puzzles!

For the left-hand column, a word X is a Narcissistic Word™ if

> X is itself an X word, according to the puzzle with that name.

Thanks to @Ankoganit for helping me realise this! See the following list:

> - [What is a Mostly Ruddy Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41789/5373) (Ruddy is a Ruddy Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Chaotic Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42256/5373) (Chaotic is a Chaotic Word™)
>
>  - [What is an Uptight™ Word?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42253/5373) (Composed is a Composed Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Composite Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/19982/5373) (Composite is a Composite Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Mostly Ruddy Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41789/5373) (Mostly is a Mostly Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Veteran Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42393/5373) (Veteran is a Veteran Word™)
>
>  - [What is an Uptight™ Word?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42253/5373) (Uptight is an Uptight Word™!)
>
>  - [What is a Narcissistic Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/43194/5373) (Narcissistic is a Narcissistic Word™, although putting it in the right-hand column would also work equally well).
>
>  - [What is an Isolated Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42934/5373) (Isolated is an Isolated Word™)
>
>  - [What Is An Explain Word?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42935/5373) (Explain is an Explain Word)
>
>  - [What is a Refreshing Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42556/5373)
>
>  - [What is a Distasteful Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/43012/5373)
>
>  - [What is an Uncopyrightable Word?™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/19916/5373)
>
>  - [What is a Viridescent Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42237/5373)

For the right-hand column, a word X is an Echoing Word™ if

> X is **not** an X word, according to the puzzle with that title.

See the following list:

> - [What is a Healthy Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42382/5373) (Healthy is not a Healthy Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Devilish Phrase™/Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42943/5373) (Devilish is not a Devilish Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Decomposed Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42794/5373) (Decomposed is not a Decomposed Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Versatile Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17879/5373) (Versatile is not a Versatile Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Surpassing Phrase™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17973/5373) (Surpassing is not a Surpassing Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Bandit Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42933/5373) (Bandit is not a Bandit Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Shy Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42124/5373) (Shy is not a Shy Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Vain Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/24643/5373) (Vain is not a Vain Word™)
>
>  - [What is a Re-Tileable Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42812/5373)
>
>  - [What is a Scientific Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/20109/5373)
>
>  - [What is a Rotten Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/24096/5373)
>
>  - [What is a Venomous Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41460/5373)
>
>  - [What is an Anagrammable Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42347/5373)
>
>  - [What is a Fantastical Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/41748/5373)

Comment: Healthy has as well.

Comment: [Devilish](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42943/9000) and [Vain](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/24643/9000)  have indeed been Word™/Phrase™ puzzles.

Comment: So has rotten and venomous

Comment: Decomposed and devilish are showing in the related listing on the right for me.

Comment: Did all the words come from the other Word™/Phrase™ puzzles? That would be interesting but not good as the rule for this puzzle.

Comment: @gtwebb Doesn't seem to be based on the type of rule used, since e.g. Healthy is on the right but Viridescent is on the left.

Comment: This solution makes me realize the puzzle is much better than I first thought. The fun bit is that `NARCISSISTIC` could have gone either way and still been right. It's the same self-referential paradox that applies to [autological words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word#Self-referential_paradox).

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Solved! :-)

Comment: @EngineerToast Technically correct, but realistically, there's no way Narcissistic isn't going to include Narcissistic. (although it easily could have if another name was chosen) :)

Comment: Tough to classify ECHOING, though.